# Docker container command not found or does not exist

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Im having troubles with Docker.

Here is my DockerFile

```
FROM alpine:3.3

WORKDIR /

COPY myinit.sh /myinit.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/myinit.sh"]
```

myinit.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo 123
```

Thats the way i build my image

```
docker build -t test  --no-cache
```

Run logs

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
Step 1 : FROM alpine:3.3
 ---> d7a513a663c1
Step 2 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Running in eda8d25fe880
 ---> 1dcad4f11062
Removing intermediate container eda8d25fe880
Step 3 : COPY myinit.sh /myinit.sh
 ---> 49234cc3903a
Removing intermediate container ffe6227c921f
Step 4 : ENTRYPOINT /myinit.sh
 ---> Running in 56d3d748b396
 ---> 060f6da19513
Removing intermediate container 56d3d748b396
Successfully built 060f6da19513
```

Thats how i run the container

```
docker run --rm --name test2  test

docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '/myinit.sh' not found or does not exist..
```

myinit.sh exist for sure. Here is ls -al

```
ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 lorddaedra  staff  136 10 май 19:43 .
drwxr-xr-x  25 lorddaedra  staff  850 10 май 19:42 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 lorddaedra  staff   82 10 май 19:51 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x   1 lorddaedra  staff   29 10 май 19:51 myinit.sh
```

Why it cant see my entrypoint script? Any solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the entrypoint script it can't find, but the shell it's referencing -- alpine:3.3 doesn't by default have bash inside it. Change your `myinit.sh` to:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

echo 123
```

i.e. referencing `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`